# Ajax textfield with EXtJs

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, response

I want to have textfield. When the user types something it should make an ajax request and offer a list on values in a drop down. Is it easy to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Sure is. Ext's example of this: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/forum-search.html